# Webpage removed from search results after protocol change

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engines

My website was running all right until my employer wanted to change protocol (`http://` to `https://`)

Since then, my website was removed from search results. I already tried using a robots.txt and it's even being show as "allowed", but It does not recognize when I try to index my page, resulting in a "Temporarily Unreachable" page.

My robots looks like this:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /Admin*

Allow: /
```

Oh, and my firewall is not blocking anything from Google.

Comment: How did you change the protocol?   Did you put redirects in place?

Comment: "Temporarily Unreachable" usually means that the site is down.   If you are sure that Googlebot isn't blocked at your firewall, have you checked an IP address rules as well?   Is it unable to access the insecure version now maybe?

Comment: Are both: http and https versions available? What page do you get when you try to open the http version? If it's anything but redirect to https, that may be the problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller another employee was responsible for doing it, but yes, the redirects are in place. While trying to access the http version, it will be automatically redirected to the secure version.
And yes, the website is up.
Not sure if helpfull, but if you want to, the address is: https://4rsistemas.com.br

Comment: @IgorGorbenkoyes, the http version is redirected to the https version. Sorry, I'm kinda new into it. How is that exactly the problem?

Comment: Your redirects are not implemented correctly.  `$ curl --head http://4rsistemas.com.br/`: `HTTP/1.1 303 See Other`   You absolutely need to change those to 301 permanent redirects

Comment: I'll try on that. Gotta ask the network guy to do that since I have no control on the ftp and web service. Anyways, hope that's the solution! By the way, how exactly have you found out this? I want to know it just for future problems.